# Should Law.SE be an automatic migration destination?

Tags: feature-request, migration

I've seen plenty of questions now that ask "Is it legal if...", or similar. I feel as if it would be valuable if Law.SE could be selected as a migration target, similarly to how Crypto.SE can be selected.

Comment: possible but we have also "is this code safe.." we should move to CodeReview.se, but it can be useful like some legal questions which are primarily administrative and thus slightly connected with InfoSec.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would be nice to have somewhere to ship those questions. But migration isn't only about getting the wrong kind of content off our site, it is also about getting the right kind of content onto the target site.

A lot of the legal questions asked here does not live up to the standards expected at law. They often lack basic details such as what jurisdiction it's in. So I'm not sure they would approve of such a change.

If I see a legal question that is not fit for fight on law, I just vote to close as off topic instead. Sometimes I comment and say something like "if you add more info it might be on topic on law, but be sure to read their guidelines before you post there".

Comment: ... and for that, in helping maintain the quality of other StackExchange sites, the non-default migrations pass through flags raised to the moderators. It's sometimes a bit slower, but we favor that speed vs. quality tradeoff.

Comment: agreed with that, also migrated one-liners that pop up occasionally do rarely get answered in law.se